# SQL Error foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I get an error that says:

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'a_schuldb.st_stunden' (errno: 150)
```

I think that is a problem with the foreign key.

Here is my code.

```
drop database if exists  a_schuldb;
create database a_schuldb;
use a_schuldb;

create table s_schueler (
s_schnr int primary key,
s_name varchar(15),
s_vorname varchar(10),
s_gebdat DATE, 
s_adresse varchar(10),
s_k_klasse char (6)
);


create table k_klassen (
k_id char(6) primary key,
k_bez varchar(25),
k_s_klaspr int,
k_s_klasprstv int,
k_l_klavst int,
foreign key (k_s_klaspr) references s_schueler(s_schnr) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade,
foreign key (k_s_klasprstv) references s_schueler(s_schnr)
on delete set null 
on update cascade ,
foreign key (k_l_klavst) references s_schueler(s_schnr)
on delete set null 
on update cascade
);

alter table s_schueler add foreign key (s_k_klasse)
references k_klassen (k_id)
on update cascade
on delete set null; 


create table l_lehrer  (
l_id char(3) primary key,
l_name varchar(15),
l_vorname varchar(10),
l_gebdat DATE, 
l_gehalt int,
l_l_chef char(3),
foreign key (l_l_chef) references l_lehrer(l_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade
);


create table r_raume  (
r_id char(5) primary key,
r_plaetze int
);


create table st_stunden (
st_k_klasse char(6),
st_stunde char(5),
st_g_fach char (3),
st_l_lehrer char(3),
st_r_raum char (5),
constraint primary key (st_k_klasse, st_stunde,st_g_fach),
foreign key (st_k_klasse) references k_klassen(k_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade,
foreign key (st_l_lehrer) references l_lehrer(l_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade,
foreign key (st_r_raum) references r_raume(r_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade
);


create table p_pruefungen (
p_date Date,
p_s_kandidat int,
p_l_pruefer char (3),
p_g_fach char(3),
p_art varchar(3),
p_note int,
constraint primary key (p_date, p_s_kandidat, p_l_pruefer,p_g_fach),
foreign key (p_s_kandidat) references s_schueler(s_schnr) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade,
foreign key (p_l_pruefer) references l_lehrer(l_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade
);

create table g_gegenstaende  (
g_id char(5) primary key,
g_bez varchar(50)
);

alter table st_stunden add foreign key (st_g_fach) references g_gegenstaende(g_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade;

alter table p_pruefungen add foreign key (p_g_fach) references g_gegenstaende(g_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade;
```

Comment: You are creating a reference to itself on this table `l_lehrer` before the table gets created. You should do as you did on the `k_klassen` create it then alter table adding the reference to itselt... Did not keep searching for such errors after finding this one

Comment: It solve your problem? May I add an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have some bugs in `st_stunden` definition:

```
foreign key (st_k_klasse) references k_klassen(k_id) 
on delete set null 
on update cascade,
```

`on delete set null` but column `st_k_klasse` disallow nulls.

same problem with columns: `p_s_kandidat` and `p_l_pruefer`

But - You can't set all of this columns to DEFAULT NULL, because they're elements of primary key.

Maybe instead of Your PK try add autoincrement column as PK, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `st_stunden` (
  `st_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `st_k_klasse` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_stunde` char(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `st_g_fach` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `st_l_lehrer` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_r_raum` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`st_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `st_k_klasse` (`st_k_klasse`,`st_l_lehrer`,`st_r_raum`),  -- optional
  KEY `st_l_lehrer` (`st_l_lehrer`),
  KEY `st_r_raum` (`st_r_raum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `st_stunden`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `st_stunden_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`st_k_klasse`) REFERENCES `k_klassen` (`k_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `st_stunden_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`st_l_lehrer`) REFERENCES `l_lehrer` (`l_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `st_stunden_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`st_r_raum`) REFERENCES `r_raume` (`r_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```